# How move file in the event of catch exception (Mule 3.2 )

Tags: file, exception, mule

In my principal flow move file from "IN" to "BackUp" but in case occurs exception I want move the file from (I don't know
) to "Error".

How move file from "my cath exception" to "Error" in Mule 3.2?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "I don't know"? If you want to move the failed message to a folder named "Error", you can include a File outbound endpoint in the catch exception strategy section of your Flow.

Answer (score 1):

Use catch exception strategy and use a file outbound endpoint there. 
You should be able to send the file to the desired location

```
<flow>
<inbound-endpoint/><!-- Fill in your details for this component -->
<outbound-endpoint/><!-- Fill in your details for this component -->
<catch-exception-strategy>
<logger message="#[payload]" level="ERROR' />
<outbound-endpoint/><!-- Fill in your details for this component -->
</catch-exception-strategy>
<flow>
```

On any exception that happens on your flow will be captured in teh exception strategy and the logic or flow you write there will be executed. In this case the paylod is written to a file in the folder that you configure within

```
</catch-exception-strategy>
```